# Is it standard to use "Defined Constant as a prefix for a function name" or a "Variable Function" in PHP?

Tags: php

**This is the PHP Code:**

```
define( 'FN_PREFIX', 'prefix_' );

${ FN_PREFIX . 'function_name' } = function( $string ) {
    echo $string;
};

$prefix_function_name( 'This is Working!!!' );
```

**The Result:**

```
This is Working!!!
```

Comment: Standard? No. There are classes and namespaces in PHP, you can use those to similar effect. However, what are you trying to solve (or understand)?

Answer (score 0):

No !!!! This is not at all standard .You have classes and methods with access specifiers and return types (PHP 7) to serve the purpose. Closure has different purpose.